# Calculating harddisk size

Tags: c, linux

I have written a code to calculate the hardisk size, but for some reason it always gives the size lesser than the actual size.

Like, 80GB will show as 74GB, and 160GB will show as 149 GB.
Where is the catch?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>


int main()
{

        long bytes = 0;
        int fd = open("/dev/sdb1", O_RDONLY);
        const unsigned long long a = (1024ULL* 1024ULL * 1024ULL);

        int retval = ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &bytes);
        int hdSize = bytes / a;

        printf(" Harddisk = %lld \n",hdSize);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply [different Gigabyte definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte#Examples_of_gigabyte-sized_storage). You use 1 GB = 2<sup>30</sup> bytes, many harddrive vendors use 10<sup>9</sup> bytes.

For instance, an "80 GB" disk from a manufacturer using the latter definition will hold 80,000,000,000 bytes, which equals 78,125,000 KB, 76,294 MB, or (as you verified) 74.51 GB where all my units use power-of-two definitions.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish and nullify this difference to get the actual size everytime?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Your code does get the correct, actual size, just in gibibytes instead of gigabytes.

Comment: unsigned long long a = (1000000000ULL);

Comment: Using 1000*1000*1000 gives the correct, as you have said abt different notations. But that's not the right way.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Pretty easy: Only convince all the marketing and sales people of every storage vendor to market their sizes in gibibytes (ugh, what a horrible name!).

Comment: @Manjabes they replaced sense of gigabyte word, bastards! Let's make gigabyte 2^30 again.

Comment: I was particularly fond of the floppy disk MBs, 1000*1024 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the difference between gigabytes and gibibytes, there's also the formatting of the partition(s) to be aware of.

All the metadata and directory structures (and journal files...) will steal some of the available space.

Another reason may be hidden rescue/restoration partitions, which pinch 5-10 GB from the end of a hard drive.